# how to approximate compute p(a|b, c) , using p(b|c), p(a|*, c), p(a), p(b), p(c)

Tags: probability, statistics, approximation

how to approximate compute p(a|b, c) , using p(b|c), p(a|*, c), p(a), p(b), p(c)

p(a|*, c), * means anythins.

p(a|*, c) = $\sum_i p(a|i, c) $

error = | p(a|b, c) - f(p(b|c), p(a|*, c), p(a), p(b), p(c)) |

Comment: does $P(A|B,C)$ mean $P(A|B\cup C)$ or $P(A|B\cap C)$?

Comment: P(A|B,C) means P(A|B∩C)

Comment: i can be A B and C or something else too?

Comment: yes, i can be anything in corpus